# Rxjava2 - how to get observer to stop emitting items after first one or use zipWith?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

The code below does the network calls fine. but it constantly emitting the same results. i want to just take the first results and stop emission. Is there not a command i can say just emit the first. i tried take(1) but that some reason changes the result size.

```
//class variables
  FeedsModel feedsModelResult;
    HashMap<Integer, ProductModel> productMap;

//method

    @Override
       protected Observable buildUseCaseObservable() {
           /* gets feedModel then parses through each feed for product IDs. then does a network call to get each product. stores retrieved
           product model in hashmap for quick retrieval. returns a pair.
            */
           return feedRepository.fetchFeeds(shopId, langId, skip)
                   .concatMap(new Function<FeedsModel, ObservableSource<List<Feed>>>() {
                       @Override
                       public ObservableSource<List<Feed>> apply(@NonNull final FeedsModel feedsModel) throws Exception {
                           feedsModelResult = feedsModel;
                           return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<Feed>>() {
                               @Override
                               public List<Feed> call() throws Exception {

                                   return feedsModel.getFeed();
                               }
                           });
                       }
                   })
                   .concatMap(new Function<List<Feed>, ObservableSource<Feed>>() {
                       @Override
                       public ObservableSource<Feed> apply(@NonNull List<Feed> feeds) throws Exception {

                           return Observable.fromIterable(feeds);
                       }
                   }).filter(new Predicate<Feed>() {
                       @Override
                       public boolean test(@NonNull Feed feed) throws Exception {
                           return feed.getProducts() != null;
                       }
                   })
                   .concatMap(new Function<Feed, ObservableSource<Double>>() {
                       @Override
                       public ObservableSource<Double> apply(@NonNull Feed feed) throws Exception {
                           return Observable.fromIterable((ArrayList<Double>) feed.getProducts());
                       }
                   })
                   .concatMap(new Function<Double, ObservableSource<ProductModel>>() {
                       @Override
                       public ObservableSource<ProductModel> apply(@NonNull Double productId) throws Exception {
                           return productsRepository.fetchProduct(productId.intValue(), shopId, langId, currency);
                       }
                   }).concatMap(new Function<ProductModel, ObservableSource<Map<Integer, ProductModel>>>() {
                       @Override
                       public ObservableSource apply(@NonNull ProductModel productModel) throws Exception {

                           productMap.put(productModel.getIdProduct(), productModel);
                           return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Map<Integer, ProductModel>>() {
                               @Override
                               public Map<Integer, ProductModel> call() throws Exception {
                                   return productMap;
                               }
                           });
                       }
                   }).concatMap(new Function<Map<Integer, ProductModel>, ObservableSource<Pair>>() {
                       @Override
                       public ObservableSource apply(@NonNull final Map<Integer, ProductModel> productModelMap) throws Exception {
                           return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable() {
                               @Override
                               public Object call() throws Exception {
                                   return Pair.create(feedsModelResult, productMap);
                               }
                           });
                       }
                   });
       }
```

UPDATE: 
in onSubscribe i keep a reference to the disposable and dispose of it in onNext() after i get the first result. is this efficient way to do it ?

at the very end of the call the results Pair.create(feedsModelResult, productMap);   I think i should be using zipWith operator to wait for all the results to complete but im not sure how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to understands your flow, but it's seems you are trying you to query some `FeedsModel` object, and to emit single `Pair` value that packs this `FeedsModel` object along with some collected map of its internal products objects its contains.

The problem is that your `Observable` is flatten may times each inner list, and tries to collect them along the way to the map, while the stream still emits those items to the end subscriber.

What you need is a stream that gets an input `FeedsModel`, collect all the items to a map and **emit only single** item which is the resulted map, then you can pair this map together with the input `FeedsModel` along with the resulted map you have just collected.
Assuming your `feedRepository.fetchFeeds` can return only single `FeedsModel` item (you can refine it by using `Single<FeedsModel>`), you will have single result here at the end stream.

a suggestion would be to use a variant of flatMap that includes result selector:

```
feedRepository.fetchFeeds(shopId, langId, skip)
 .flatMap(feedsModel ->
         getProductsMapFromFeedsModelObservable(feedsModel, shopId, langId, currency)
         ,(feedsModel, productsMap) ->
               Pair.create(feedsModel, productsMap)
         );
```

and the `getProductsMapFromFeedsModelObservable()` is an `Observable` that collects products to products map from input FeedsModel:

```
private Observable<HashMap<Integer, ProductModel>> getProductsMapFromFeedsModelObservable(
            FeedsModel feedsModel, int shopId, int langId, int currency) {
        return Observable.fromIterable(feedsModel.getFeed())
                .filter(feed -> feed.getProducts() != null)
                .flatMapIterable(feed -> feed.getProducts())
                .flatMap(productId -> productsRepository.fetchProduct(productId.intValue(), shopId, langId, currency))
                .reduce(new HashMap<Integer, ProductModel>(),
                        (productsMap, productModel) -> {
                            productsMap.put(productModel.getIdProduct(), productModel);
                            return productsMap;
                        })
                .toObservable();
    }
```

`reduce()` is used to collect all items to map and emit single item, `flatMap()` is used here as you can gain from parallel execution, `concat()` probably is not needed anyway, not sure what why it was in first place (preserve order?).